# Adding a Matrix and an Array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm currently trying to add a Matrix with an Array.

This is the code I have right now:

```
public void add(Matrix m) {

    for(int i = 0; i == values.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j == values.length; j++) {
            m.values[i][j] = m.values[i][j] + values[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

Comment: `i == values.length` -> `i < values.length`. same for `j`

Comment: @Eran Already tried, I get this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Matrix.add(Matrix.java:23)
 at Matrix.main(Matrix.java:101) then.

Comment: Well, do `m.values` and `values` have the same dimensions? Do the number of rows equal the number of columns? You are assuming these things.

Comment: Matrix: Matrix m = new Matrix(new int[][] { { 2, 4, 5 }, { 3, 7, 2 },
    { -2, 0, 1 }, { 5, 1, 1 } });

Comment: values: private int[][] values;

Comment: OK, so the next thing is to change `j < values.length` to `j < values[0].length`

Comment: try to use `for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {`

Comment: Thanks, there is no error now, but the multiplication somehow still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java language there are no word of matrix or 2D or nD array there are an array of array.

About your problem try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
```

- The first loop `for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {` return
  array by array `{ 2, 4, 5 }` and `{ 3, 7, 2 }` and `{ -2, 0, 1` } and `{ 5, 1, 1 }`
- The second loop `for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {` return
  value by values of each array from the first loop if we took the first array it will return `2` and `4` and `5`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. Can you explain the second part in code?

Comment: @TimoGüntner the second part is equivalent to `int[] array = values[i]; for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {` that's it you get it ;)

Comment: It's still not working for me. Can you help me once again and I'll mark you as the best answer.

Comment: The values of the Matrix M don't change. Can you give me an working example?

Comment: @TimoGüntner can you share the full code please there are many anonymity things in your code for example what is `values` and what is `m`

Comment: @TimoGüntner try this https://ideone.com/K6kTnc i fixed many problems in your code hope this can help you, if not you can ask there are no problem with me ;)

Comment: Thank you, but somehow the values of the Matrix still do not change. Any idea why?

Comment: @TimoGüntner of course you have to use `m = m.add(n);` instead of `m.add(n);` i forgot this point

Answer (score 1):

Check for the dimensions of the Array and the Matrix to be the same.

```
public void add(Matrix m) {
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            m.values[i][j] = m.values[i][j] + values[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Matrix.add(Matrix.java:23)
 at Matrix.main(Matrix.java:101)

Comment: Do the matrix and 2D array have the same dimensions?  This error seems to imply that this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add matrices, you can use loops in Java, but also streams. This is a sample implementation of matrix addition using streams:

```
public class MatrixOperations {

    public static double[][] add(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
        return range(0, a.length).boxed().collect(
                () -> new double[a.length][a[0].length], // create the accumulator matrix which is to be returned
                (acc, row) -> range(0, a[row].length).forEach(col -> acc[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col]), // sum each value
                (acc, r) -> {}); // ignore
    }

    // Test method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] a = {{1.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 2.0}};
        double[][] b = {{.0, .0}, {7.0, 5.0}, {2.0, 1.0}};
        double[][] sum = add(a, b);
        Stream.of(sum).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you run this class you will get the following output:

```
[1.0, 3.0]
[8.0, 5.0]
[3.0, 3.0]
```